# Report Builder Total of Grouped Averages

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report

how can I summarize group average in a table I have earlier created. I don't want have the averages of the whole table.

```
1          A       10
2          B       20 
3          B       15
4          A       20
5          B       10
By Group   A       15
           B       11.67 
Total              16.67
```

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is the field being grouped for the average fixed or variable? That is, is it always _either_ `A` _or_ `B` or can it have any value?

Comment: What specific version of SSRS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume table `T` has following schema:

```
id         name     num
1          A        10
2          B        20 
3          B        15
4          A        20
5          B        10
By Group   A        15
           B        15   -- <= Note: this should be 15.
Total               30
```

Then, you can use

```
SELECT SUM(a) FROM (
  SELECT AVG(num) AS a
  FROM T
  GROUP BY name
) AS gavg;
```

Check out the [**demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ab52/9). Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Because I have some graphs with a different grouping further down in the report I couldn't use that solution.

Comment: I used an expression in the Total  =Sum(Avg(Fields!name.Value,"By Group"),"All")

Comment: @SQuirreL sorry I can't catch it. Could you give me an example?

Comment: You can create expressions that calculate an aggregate of an aggregate. For example, in a cell in the row group header that is associated with a group based on year, you can calculate the average monthly sales for year by using the expression =Avg(Sum(Fields!Sales.Value,"Month"),"Year").